# How to make CMake re-run from scratch without deleting and re-creating the build directory

Tags: cmake

Is there a way to make CMake do a distclean?

For example, I create a build directory, and run `cmake` in there. Then I make a change to the CMakeLists.txt, and re-run CMake. It's not clear whether this causes my changes to be used, or whether CMake just takes the answers from the cache.

So I remove the build directory, re-create it, and then run `cmake` again.

Is there a way to accomplish this in CMake without deleting the build directory? Is there an equivalent target to the standard distclean target?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what the CMake pre-defined target `ZERO_CHECK` is for. It is a build system regeneration target. When you compile one of your pre-existing CMake projects, the `ZERO_CHECK` target should always run first to check to see if *any* of your CMake files have changed since the last build. If they have, CMake will re-run and regenerate the build system using your latest CMake files.

You just have to be careful with [cached](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set.html#set-cache-entry) variables. These look something like this in the code, and typically appear in the CMake GUI display for easy editing:

```
set(MY_VAR "ExampleString" CACHE STRING "My string variable")
```

The documentation states:

> Since cache entries are meant to provide user-settable values this does not overwrite existing cache entries by default. Use the `FORCE` option to overwrite existing entries.

Cached variables will **retain** their original value unless you explicitly change or unset them, by adding the `FORCE` attribute to the `set()` command above, using the [`unset()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/unset.html#unset-normal-variable-or-cache-entry) command, or deleting them from the cache. So, changing the string `MY_VAR` to something else in the code:

```
set(MY_VAR "OtherString" CACHE STRING "My string variable")
```

will not change the variable's value, because the original string is *cached*. 
You can delete the variable from cache (or modify the cached value) from the CMake GUI window, or by manually modifying the `CMakeCache.txt` file in your CMake build folder.

---

If you're looking for a way to shortcut removing and re-creating the build directory, simply deleting the `CMakeCache.txt` file in the build folder should achieve the same effect.